# How to get the selected radiobutton value in apex?

Tags: apex, selectradio

I have use the following code I would like to get the radiobutton value in the apex.
I have checked the one option button and click the button  (to call the method OptionVlaue())
I have checked the value, but it is null.
How to get the selected radiobutton value in apex?

**Apex:**

```
public String optionValue { get; set; }    
    Public void OptionVlaue(){        
        system.debug('<<option value>>'+OptionVlaue);        
}
```

**VF page:**

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!optionValue}">
       <apex:selectOption itemValue="1"></apex:selectOption>
       <apex:selectOption itemValue="2"> </apex:selectOption>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally a selected value will assigned to the variable automatically when you submit the form. The syntax is very easy:

- Define a new variable
- Create a new select list
- Submit the form (with an action:support for example)
- Check selected variable in controller

Apex class:

```
public with sharing MyClass{

    public String selectedValue { get; set; }    

    public MyClass(){
        // Here initializing the variable. If you want to preselect some radio button  
        // just assign it value to the variable here (eg. selectedValue = '1';)
        selectedValue = '';
    }

    public void checkSelectedValue(){        
        system.debug('Selected value is: ' + selectedValue);        
    } 
}
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!selectedValue}">
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="1"></apex:selectOption>
    <apex:selectOption itemValue="2"> </apex:selectOption>

    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" 
                        action="{!checkSelectedValue}" 
                        reRender="none">
</apex:selectRadio>
```

Comment: Great answer! worked for me. Thanks.